# Dynamically append one component into another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Here is my stackblitz link: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboard-inchara-npb4he?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I am trying to append the 'table' component inside the #test of app component, when the visualization type is 'table'. For which, I am calling the `createTable()` which creates and appends `<app-table>` tags into the #test div.

`<app-table>` tag is present in the DOM but not the content of table.component.html (i.e, table works!)
This could be because it is a mere tag and not a compiled component.

How do I get the content of table component displayed inside of app component?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @eko : I tried, it did not seem to work for me. The approach could have gone wrong. Could you please help me out?

Comment: you can add `<angular-table></angular-table>` in `app component html`

Comment: @Exterminator: I want to append the table ONLY when the visualization type == 'table', at a particular iteration. By adding the tags, the table component will always appear.

Comment: create a global variable naming type anything you want and add `*ngif="type === 'table' "` to `<angular-table></angular-table>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 createTable() {
    this.container.clear(); 
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TableComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);  

  }
```

Your Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboard-inchara-3xrjkj

Comment: I want the table to get inserted inside #charts and not inside another #container

Comment: you mean inside div?

Comment: Yes. Inside <div #charts id="test">
</div>

Comment: move ng-template inside that div check the stackblitz

Comment: Doing so, appends table component just once. Please check appObject, visualization type == table is twice, which means graph-graph-table-graph-table should appear in the DOM. Inspect my stackblitz output to see, app-table tag being inserted twice as per the condition

Comment: check the stackblitz now. now it is being rendered two times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180054/discussion-between-inchara-raveendra-and-chellappan).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to add components dynamically. This is further explained in the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader). Added a full solution in stackblitz: 
[ComponentFactoryResolver](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboard-inchara-fcsh55). In summary this is what I did:

table creation in `app.component.ts`:

```
createTable(container) {
  let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TableComponent);
  let viewContainerRef = this.insTable.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();
  let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  // let e = document.createElement("app-table");
  // container.appendChild(e);
}
```

The directive used as and anchor point `table.directive.ts`:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ins-table]',
})
export class TableDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

And the `app.component.html`:

```
<div #charts id="test">
  <ng-template ins-table></ng-template>
</div>
```

And the `app.module.ts` with proper declarations to make it all work:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';
import { TableDirective } from './table/table.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ChartModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, TableComponent, TableDirective],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [HttpClientModule],
  entryComponents: [
    TableComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried, it did not seem to work for me. The approach could have gone wrong. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra please check my full solution

Comment: Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboard-inchara-c53fd4?file=src/app/app.component.ts